# Why is my printer scaling everything down, and how do I fix it?

Tags: 18.04, printing, scaling

I have a Brother MFC-9330CDW printer on my home LAN. Whenever I print to it from my Linux box running Ubuntu 18.04, everything is a tiny bit smaller than it should be. I've verified this printing from both GIMP and Inkscape.

I tried making a 10-inch (254mm) long line in Inkscape and the resulting line is only 242.75mm long.

In Inkscape Scale is set to 100%, and in the printer's settings in Printers the scale is also set to 100% and "Scale to Fit" is unchecked.

I tried adjusting the scale in Printers to 105%, but this seems to have no effect. If I adjust the scale in Inkscape to 104.6% it works, but only for that printout, and only in Inkscape.

If I print to the same printer from Inkscape running on a Mac, the scale is correct. I tried printing from a second machine that's also running Ubuntu 18.04, and with almost no modifications from a fresh install, and it has the exact same weird scaling.

Why is my printer scaling everything down when I print from Ubuntu, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps you need to install the proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 3):

I followed [@GabrielaGarcia](https://askubuntu.com/users/880592/gabrielagarcia)'s advice and installed Brother's drivers. I downloaded [these two .deb files](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc9330cdw_us_eu_as&os=128), installed them, and then followed the directions on their download page. To paraphrase:

1. Go to the CUPS config at http://localhost:631/printers and choose the printer.
2. In the Administration selctor choose "Modify Printer". (Note: this doesn't work in for me in Google Chrome, but it works fine in Firefox.)
3. Set Device to either "LPD/LPR Host or Printer" or "AppSocket/HP JetDirect"           for Device
4. Set Device URI to `lpd://*printer's address*/binary_p1`
5. Set Make/Manufacturer to "Brother"
6. Set Model/Driver based on printer model (make sure to avoid old "cups" driver that will be near the top of the list -- that's the old one.)

This fixes the scale issue.

**However**, one big annoyance is that printing from the manual feed no longer seems to auto-center the printing correctly. For example, if I try to print an envelope, the contents are printed too high and too far to the left. To compensate for this, I need to set my paper size to landscape US letter, and then place the contents vertically centered and right aligned.

Comment: Honestly, best answer. I have Epson XP-750 which has been plagued by scaling issues. There were no new drivers for my printer on the list (only old ones at the top) so I gambled a little and chose driver for XP-860. That opened so many more possibilities for my printer, including printing CDs, which my printer is capable of, but the option just wasn't there before I modified settings (and I was wondering why, now I know). I haven't tried printing any CDs yet but scaling issues are gone! Thank you!